# Prove the second derivative limit formula

Tags: calculus

for a twice differentiable function $f(x)$, $$f''(a)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}$$

I proved it using Taylor's formula when $f''(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$. But I don't know how to prove if $f''(x)$ is discontinuous like $$f(x)=x^4\sin\frac{1}{x}$$ except $x=0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: The formula as stated is wrong in at least two places, check again

Comment: Oh I've got it!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But that's not the most important part of the question...

Comment: Yes it is. It's much much harder to prove false things than to prove true ones. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes Omg does it mean it's false?!

Comment: The formula you originally wrote was incorrect, yes, so proving it correct would have been very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Taylor's formula (one of them) says that if $f''(a)$ exists (no continuity assumption on $f''$ – nor even the assumption $f''$ exists anywhere else – is needed), then

$$f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a)h + (f''(a)/2)h^2 +o(h^2).$$

Comment: (+1) How did this not receive one up vote?  It leads immediately to the second symmetric derivative.  Interestingly, the second symmetric derivative can exist while the second derivative fails to exist.

Comment: Hey MV, thanks. Remember this is MSE, a land where strange things happen.

Answer (score 1):

The top and the bottom of the fraction in the limit are both differentiable functions of $h$, and both tend to $0$ as $h$ tends to zero, so L'Hopital's rule applies.

The limit should be the same as

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a-h)}{2h}\\
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{2h}+\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a)-f'(a-h)}{2h}\\
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{2h}+\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a-h)-f'(a)}{-2h}\\
=\frac{f''(a)}{2}+\frac{f''(a)}{2}=f''(a)
$$